# Emacs doesn't evaluate all expressions at neither init.el nor .emacs, and emacs doesn't seem to record changes in .emacs either init.el

Tags: emacs, command

All the time, when I try to C-backspace, it returning message: *command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, hixac/backward-kill-word*

```
(defun hixac/backward-kill-word ()
  "Remove all whitespace if the character behind the cursor is whitespace, otherwise remove a word."
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-back "[ \n]")
      ;; delete horizontal space before us and then check to see if we
      ;; are looking at a newline
      (progn (delete-horizontal-space 't)
             (while (looking-back "[ \n]")
               (backward-delete-char 1)))
    ;; otherwise, just do the normal kill word.
    (backward-kill-word 1)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-<backspace>") 'hixac/backward-kill-word)
```

I have no idea how to deal with it.

I tried to change various keybindings I tried `[C-backspace]` and `(kbd "C-\d")` and others.. Something has been worked but after restarting emacs returns to it previous state with above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed error. Emacs actually didn't evaluate ".emacs" either "init.el" file it's actually evaluated ".emacs.elc" the file of compiled version of old ".emacs".

It is very confuse behavior and I spent at fixing it a lot of time.

And afterall I can say that ".emacs.elc" has a higher priority unlike ".emacs" for god's sake.

Comment: Indeed; see `C-h i g (emacs)Find Init` for the priority order, and keep in mind that byte-compiled versions of files are preferred to their uncompiled equivalents (the `load-prefer-newer` variable notwithstanding).  Nowadays there might be native-compiled code as well.  To avoid such issues it's generally not recommended to byte-compile your init file, so just stay aware of these things if you continue doing so.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that function `command-execute` received `hixac/backward-kill-word` as an *argument* and it's not a command. But it *is* a command, from the code you show.

Does `M-x hixac/backward-kill-word` work? Can you reproduce the problem starting Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If so, provide a step-by-step recipe saying what you do and what you see.

When you say something like *"Something has been worked but after restarting emacs"* it suggests you don't have a reproducible recipe and aren't sure what you might have done. The code you show definitely defines that function as a command. So you need to provide some more info, for us to figure out what's going on.

Also, consider changing the question title - it doesn't seem to have anything to do with customizing any function.

Comment: Thanks for help. 
`M-x hixac/backward-kill-word` doesn't seems to work, because I cannot see function in the list.
By "customize function" I meant custom function, sorry for poor english.

Comment: Cannot see that function in what list? Do you mean that `M-x` doesn't recognize that function name?

Comment: Yes, correct. No idea why.

Comment: Are you sure you spelled the command the same way? If you included an `interactive` spec in your function definition, which your code here shows you did, then the function has to be a command, i.e., it has to satisfy `commandp`.

Comment: I'm absolute sure about it. I would like to attach screenshot of it, but I can't.